# Make a Jquery array from a javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

I am using the following code to pull some mileage data from Google Maps Distance Matrix. The problem is it comes back as plain javascript. I have managed to get it to put the data into a javascript array, so I have :

```
arrResults[0]
arrResults[1]
arrResults[2]
arrResults[3]
```

But I want to use the array in Jquery now, but cant work out how to convert it into a Jquery array ?.

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "#submit" ).click(function() {
        $("#my_map").gmap3({
      getdistance:{
        options:{ 
          origins:["pe219px","ng323rj"], 
          destinations:["pe219px","ng323rj"],
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
          unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
        },
        callback: function(results, status){
          var html = "";
          var arrResults = [];
          if (results){
            for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++){
              var elements = results.rows[i].elements;
              for(var j=0; j<elements.length; j++){
                switch(elements[j].status){
                  case "OK":
                  var sd=$(this).text();  
                    html += parseInt(elements[j].distance.text) + "<br />";
        arrResults.push(elements[j].distance.text); 

                    break;
                  case "NOT_FOUND":
                    html += "The origin and/or destination of this pairing could not be geocoded<br />";
                    break;
                  case "ZERO_RESULTS":
                    html += "No route could be found between the origin and destination.<br />";
                    break;
                }
              }
            } 
          } else {
            html = "error";
          }
          $("#my_map").html( html );
        }
      }
    });
         }); });
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="my_map"></div>
    <p><a id="submit" href="#">Submit</a></p>
```

Comment: jQuery _is_ JavaScript -- what are you asking?

Comment: what is jQuery array? What you expect to do with the array?

Comment: He wants an Object for associative access to values, i'd assume?

Comment: If I put a jquery click function at the end of the page on a view result button  and get it to alert (arrResults[2]); nothing happens, so I presumed it was because it was plain javascript making the call and couldnt be used 'as is' straight inside a jquery function ?.

Comment: `var arrResults` declares an array local to that function. Another function won't be able to access it.

Comment: How can I make it available in all functions ?, is that possible ?.

Comment: As the others have said, jQuery is javascript, so what's the question? Biggest improvement to the code would be not to use `html += ...`, which is memory-hungry. Instead, `var html = [];`, then `html.push(...)` inside the loop and finally `html.join('')` put the pieces together. This is standard fare for building HTML in javascript.

Comment: "How can I make it available in all functions?". You have two options (i) pass the variable/object to the function(s) that need it; (ii) declare `var foo' in a scope which is common to the function(s) that need it (global if you have to though it's best avoided).

Answer (score 0):

It slightly more problematic because you're using the `gmap3` plugin, but here's how I would approach the problem.

First: *redacted (see edits for more details)*

Second, make `arrResults` available globally to your functions by declaring it at the top of the IIFE. Don't redeclare it anywhere else.

Third, separate out your callback logic from the ajax function into a new function. It makes the code easier to read. Something like `processData()`.

Third, once the AJAX is done and your `processData` function has finished its run-through, use `jQuery` to add a new `#viewresults` button to your page.

```
$('body').append('<input id="viewresults" type="submit" value="View results"/>')
```

You do this because AJAX is `asyncronous`. Clicking the `viewresults` button before the data has been collected would result in either an error or nothing, so it makes sense (for your code at least) to have the button only available once the data is available.

I've provided a summary of these thoughts in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/a2B5P/) (untested, but should give you a few clues). I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Andy, there's already a `$( document ).ready(function() {...})` wrapper, which should at least be considered before making a dedicated wrapper.

Comment: You're right. Just got used to doing it that way because I generally have non-jQuery code in my apps before I start using jQuery. Redacted that part of the question.